# Graph as a function itself?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In my lecture notes on real analysis there are a few examples for curves, tangent vector and length of curves. One of the examples is:

> A graph $c(t) = (t,f(t))$ where $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is
> continuously differentiable, has tangent vector $c' = (1,f')$ and
> length $L(c) = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + (f'(t))^2} dt$.

Now what confuses me a little bit is that a graph usually is a set not a function. Of course, for any function $f:X \to Y$ we can define a new function $g$ with the graph of $f$ as its range, i.e. $g:X \to X \times Y, g(x)=(x,f(x))$, but I feel like it is a bit weird to refer to this function as a graph.

Are my lecture notes simply a bit sloppy or do we generally refer to functions such as $g$ in my example as graphs as well?

Comment: It's indeed a bit sloppy. But since we want to measure the length of the graph (as a set), we should have a *curve* to 'walk it through', whose image is the graph.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree that it makes sense in that regard, I simply wanted to make sure I am not missing anything fundamental here.

Comment: It may looks strange, but function formally is defined through graph, not reverse. So firstly we define graph with particular properties and then build function from it. So it is possible to make sense for tangent to graph.

Comment: Thanks. Are you talking about the fact that functions are nothing but a special kind of relation, and thus a subset of $X \times Y$ where $X,Y$ are the domain and co-domain?